# How to optionally authenticate with Laravel Sanctum?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-sanctum

I'm using [Laravel Sanctum](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum) to authenticate users. I'd like to have a route that can be accessed by guests and logged in users. Logged in users send an API Token in the Authorization header.

I've tried making a route without authentication, but that way I can't see the logged in user.

```
Route::get('noauth', function() {
  return Auth::check();
});
```

`GET /noauth with auth header returns false, user is not logged in`
`GET /noauth without auth header returns false, user is not logged in`

I've also tried using `auth:sanctum` middleware, but that way guests can't access the page.

```
Route::get('yesauth', function() {
  return Auth::check();
})->middleware('auth:sanctum');
```

`GET /yesauth with auth header returns true, the user is logged in`
`GET /yesauth withouth auth header returns 401, unauthorized`

The solution should return true with auth headers, and false without auth headers.

Comment: Try `return Auth::guard('web')->check();` for me?

Comment: @ceejayoz It returned false regardless of auth headers. I may have misconfigured something, because I only use this laravel app for APIs. And `Auth::guard('api')` returns errors.

Comment: if you do `auth('sanctum')->user()`, you can get the user. It will return null if the user is not logged in. `

Comment: `Auth::guard('sanctum')->user()` worked with me.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`Auth` is using the `web` guard by default. Change it to `sanctum` in `/config/auth.php`:

```
'defaults' => [
    // 'guard' => 'web',
    'guard' => 'sanctum',
    'passwords' => 'users',
],
```

Comment: This option controls the default authentication `guard` for both `api` and `web` group. so this can break the web group routes auth check.

Answer (score 3):

You can check if there is token in the request.

If token is present try to get the user from Sanctum auth guard and assign it as the current user.

```php
if (request()->bearerToken() && $user = Auth::guard('sanctum')->user()) {
    Auth::setUser($user);
}

return Auth::check() // false for guest users, true if valid token present
```

And make sure NOT to use auth:sanctum middleware